# foreign data wrapper do not work on localhost

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper

I have a virtual machine with postgresql 9.2 and an other with postgresql 9.4.
I would like create foreign data wrapper, here is what i do :

```
create extension postgres_fdw;
CREATE SERVER si_orleans_db 
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw 
OPTIONS (dbname 'db_SAMPLE', port '5432', host 'localhost');
CREATE USER MAPPING for user 
SERVER si_orleans_db 
OPTIONS (user 'user', password 'password');
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE db_SAMPLE
(
sample_id integer NOT NULL,
)
SERVER si_orleans_db OPTIONS (schema_name 'data', table_name 'sample')
```

when i execute i do not have error, but when i do :

```
select * from dbSAMPLE;
```

the select return this error :

ERREUR:  could not connect to server "si_orleans_db"
DETAIL:  FATAL:  authentification Ident échouée pour l'utilisateur « user »

but when i replace :

```
create extension postgres_fdw;
CREATE SERVER si_orleans_db 
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw 
OPTIONS (dbname 'db_SAMPLE', port '5432', host 'localhost');
```

by

```
create extension postgres_fdw;
CREATE SERVER si_orleans_db 
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw 
OPTIONS (dbname 'db_SAMPLE', port '5432', host '192.168.10.158');
```

"select * from db_SAMPLE" work perfectly

192.168.10.158 = IP address of virtual machine with postgresql 9.2

you have an idee to solve my problem?

thanks a lot

Comment: Not sure, but I think this happens when your server's `pg_hba.conf` has no authentication rules for incoming IPv6 connections, but your OS is resolving `localhost` to an IPv6 address. Try using `127.0.0.1` instead.

Comment: hello, thanks for your suggestion but i try with 127.0.0.1 and i have the same error.I have this line in my ph_hba.conf file : 
`code
    #TYPE DATABASE USER ADDRESS METHOD
    host all all 127.0.0.1/32 ident
    host all all ::1/128 ident

Comment: OK, that explains it. Removing those lines would probably fix it, but you might break something else. Can you ask the person who wrote that conf file?